# Combine an IQueryable and a List to a new class (type)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query written which returns a list of services, including an ID (resourceID) for who performed this service. I need to take this resourceID and use it as an input parameter for an existing method which will return an IQueryable result set of the resource details.

What I need to do from here is take *some* of the resource details returned from the GetResource method (iQueryable type) and add it to a list of a new class "People" along with a list of the services. i.e. a person will likely have more than one service. The end result is a List of people with properties from the resource result and a sublist of services performed by each person.

Essentially there are two methods that run linq queries that return a result sets of different types, I need to combine those results into a new type but I only need some of the fields returned by both.

I already have a linq query that returns a list of services:

```
public class Services
{

    public string Activity { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateProvided { get; set; }
    public Int32? ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    public string ServiceCode { get; set; }
    public string ServiceStatus { get; set; }
```

There is another method that will return an IQueryable of Providers:

```
    public long EId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

- ~ 50 other fields...

What I need to do is take the List of Services, lookup the Provider and combine those results into this new class (type):

```
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public long EId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Services> Services { get; set; }
```

My first time asking here, so please let me know if I am unclear or if you need additional details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post code, including class definitions and sample data, giving expected inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: -1 missing minimal example

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
var services = GetServices();
var providers = GetProviders();

var combined = providers.Select(x =>
new{
        EId,
        Firstname,
        Lastname,
        EmailAddress,
        Services = services.Where(
                   y=> y.ResourceId == x.ResourceId
        ).ToList()
});
```